# Simulating 3 serial events with .animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I use `.animate()` in jQuery to simulate the duration of a race. This works fine, but is not as good as I want.

The race are three serial events, where someone can be the fastest in the first event, and the slowest in the last event. Hope you know what I mean? ;-)

So is there a way, to do a simulation of the times with `.animate()` or do you have any other ideas?

thx

Comment: you can use javascript `Date` object. `var start = new Date(); var end = new Date(); var duration = start - end;`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, but is it a [Progress Bar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar) that you are after? Simulation of the times would require you to use a [Jquery timer](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to update it periodically

Comment: it is something like a Progress Bar. I would like to simulate the race time of a triathlon. Three events (swim, bike, run) which are serial. Person 1 could swim faster, but ride the bike slower. I just implemented total times, but I would be able to show, when person1 is swimming faster but riding the bike slower.